# Validate multiple checkboxes, minimum one required

Tags: jquery

We are creating a advertising form, and our jQuery coder is in Syria, and unfortunately caught up in the ugliness there.

So whilst he at present cannot assist with some code he made for us, I have an issue I think could be solved quite easily.

We have a stepped form, you know: Complete step 1, move on to step 2 etc etc.
On step 4, we have multiple checkboxes, that we require a user to check at least ONE.

If they check ONE they can proceed to the next step.. if they don't click any we show an error message.

So this is our js:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.formToWizard = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({  
        submitButton: "" 
    }, options); 

    var element = this;

    var steps = $(element).find("fieldset");
    var count = steps.size();
    var submmitButtonName = "#" + options.submitButton;
    $(submmitButtonName).hide();

    // 2
    $(element).before("<ul id='steps'></ul>");

    steps.each(function(i) {
        $(this).wrap("<div id='step" + i + "'></div>");
        $(this).append("<p id='step" + i + "commands'></p>");

        // 2
        var name = $(this).find("legend").html();
        $("#steps").append("<li id='stepDesc" + i + "'>Step " + (i + 1) + "<span>" + name + "</span></li>");

        if (i == 0) {
            createNextButton(i);
            selectStep(i);
        }
        else if (i == count - 1) {
            $("#step" + i).hide();
            createPrevButton(i);
        }
        else {
            $("#step" + i).hide();
            createPrevButton(i);
            createNextButton(i);
        }
    });

    function createPrevButton(i) {
        var stepName = "step" + i;
        $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='javascript:;' id='" + stepName + "Prev' class='purple button'>Back</a>&nbsp;");

        $("#" + stepName + "Prev").bind("click", function(e) {
            $("#" + stepName).hide();

            if($(this).attr('id') == "step4Prev" && $('li#stepDesc3 del').legnth > 0){
                i--;
            }
            $("#step" + (i - 1)).show();
            $(submmitButtonName).hide();
            selectStep(i - 1);
        });
    }

    function createNextButton(i) {
        var stepName = "step" + i;
        $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='javascript:;' id='" + stepName + "Next' class='purple button'>Next</a>");

        $("#" + stepName + "Next").bind("click", function(e) {
            var div = $('div#'+ stepName);
            $(div).find('.field_help').remove();
            if( $(div).find('input:text[value=""]').length > 0 ||
                $(div).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0 ||
                $(div).find('select option:first-child:selected').length > 0 ||
                $(div).find('textarea').val() == ""
                ){
                    $(div).prepend('<p class="field_help"> Please complete all fields before moving to next step</p>');
                    return false;
                }
            if($(this).attr('id') == "step2Next" ){
                if($(div).find('select[name="type"]').val() == "land"){
                    i++;
                    $('li#stepDesc3').html('<del>'+$('li#stepDesc3').html()+'</del>');
                }else{
                    if($('li#stepDesc3 del').legnth > 0){
                        $('li#stepDesc3').html($('li#stepDesc3 del').html());
                    }
                }
            }

            $("#" + stepName).hide();
            $("#step" + (i + 1)).show();
            if (i + 2 == count)
                $(submmitButtonName).show();
            selectStep(i + 1);
        });
    }

    function selectStep(i) {
        $("#steps li").removeClass("current");
        $("#stepDesc" + i).addClass("current");
    }

}
})(jQuery);
```

And this is the form area for the checkboxes:

```
<div class="master-container">
                <div class="lefthandblock">
                    <div class="sort left">
                        <span id="checkbox3Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="heating" id="checkbox3" /></span><p class="labeller">Heating</p>
                        <span id="checkbox4Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="aircon" id="checkbox4" /></span><p class="labeller">Air Conditioning</p>
                        <span id="checkbox5Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="ensuite" id="checkbox5" /></span><p class="labeller">Master En-suite</p>
                        <span id="checkbox6Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="builtins" id="checkbox6" /></span><p class="labeller">Built in Robes</p>
                        <span id="checkbox7Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="newkitchen" id="checkbox7" /></span><p class="labeller">New Kitchen</p>
                        <span id="checkbox8Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="rumpus" id="checkbox8" /></span><p class="labeller">Rumpus / Family Room</p>
                        <span id="checkbox9Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="intspa" id="checkbox9" /></span><p class="labeller">Inside spa</p>
                        <span id="checkbox10Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="media" id="checkbox10" /></span><p class="labeller">Media Room</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <!--//left hand-->
                <!--right hand-->
                <div class="righthandblock">
                    <div class="sort left">
                        <span id="checkbox11Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="fans" id="checkbox11" /></span><p class="labeller">Ceiling Fans</p>
                        <span id="checkbox12Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="highceilings" id="checkbox12" /></span><p class="labeller">High Ceilings</p>
                        <span id="checkbox13Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="insulated" id="checkbox13" /></span><p class="labeller">Insulated</p>
                        <span id="checkbox14Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="phase" id="checkbox14" /></span><p class="labeller">3 Phase Power</p>
                        <span id="checkbox15Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="internet" id="checkbox15" /></span><p class="labeller">Broadband / Internet</p>
                        <span id="checkbox16Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="floor" id="checkbox16" /></span><p class="labeller">Polished Floors</p>
                        <span id="checkbox17Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" name="internal[]" value="granny" id="checkbox17" /></span><p class="labeller">Granny Flat</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

The issue is that at present the javascript will only validate if the user ticks every single checkbox.

Perhaps it's obvious perhaps it isn't, but I cannot figure it out.

ADDED:

with checkbox ticked this is the html.

```
<span id="checkbox4Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap wrapChecked">
<input id="checkbox4" class="styledCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="aircon" name="internal[]" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)">
</span>
```

if we untick this is the html.

```
<span id="checkbox4Wrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap">
<input id="checkbox4" class="styledCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="aircon" name="internal[]" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)">
</span>
```

Comment: It's *really* hard to see the *single* line in there related to counting checked boxes. *Whew* That's some pretty gnarly JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(div).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0
```

This line says "if I have any checkboxes not checked", so the behavior you're seeing is what I'd expect. Don't you want to count the number of *checked* boxes and make sure it's > 0?

Comment: Probably `>= 1` instead of `> 1`, or `> 0`.

Comment: neither of the above, allows this step to validate. We still get message: Please complete all fields before moving to next step , using $(div).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length >= 1 ||

Comment: @422 That's because the code you pasted there is still checking for unchecked boxes. Look for *checked* boxes; Alex even provided an alternate selector, for mine, just take out the `not` part.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, but I dont get it. I have this now
$(div).find('input[name="internal[]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
     $(div).find('input[name="external[]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
still doesnt work

Comment: @422 I guess you'd want if the (count_of_checked == 0), since the whole block is looking for failure conditions. Don't know what that "external" thing is about, I don't see that in the HTML. Bottom line is that the logic flaw has been identified--you should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Basically I want event to wait for checkbox value to equal 1. So if I change above code to length >= 1 this should work ? External is for step 5 ... but it doesnt work

Comment: @422 ... As written, the validation code is looking for a failure condition. It's a failure if the number of checked boxes equals 0, your code looks for boxes named "internal[]" and "external[]". If you're checking for checkboxes that aren't currently on the page, or aren't currently visible, none of them will be checked, and your validation will fail. My solution checks for *any* checkboxes regardless of their name--that may or may not be what you want, but if you use a selector that has no elements, you'll get a zero.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but please be gentle. All code is on the page. The elements do indeed have selectors, as seen in my inital post. I am presuming when a PAGE loads, all checkboxes are indeed Zero. So the code will not validate until one is pressed with the associate selector, I am not very good with js which I also posted with the question, but I am sure that >=1 means checkbox value is equal to or greater than 1 which is a checked state, and if we have selector set as [internal] then if that set of selectors is equal to 1 or more it should validate shouldnt it ?

Comment: @422 The length comparison has to do with how many checkboxes are checked, it has nothing to do with the checkbox value itself being >= 1, a checkbox value doesn't even need to be numeric. The validation code is looking for *failure conditions*: that means no checkboxes checked, meaning the length of the results of the jquery selector's `find` method is zero.

Comment: @422 Again, the validation checks for error conditions--no checkboxes checked. `$(div).find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0`; see [my fork](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/wxkF2/). But there are other issues beyond that.

Comment: Ok thanks, i think this is really beyond my capability, sincerely appreciate all of your help. Will select as answer even though your assistance hasnt solved my problem. Such a shame on here we cant share code privately, else i could just show the url of our dev site. Thanks very much tho.

Comment: @422 That JS is beyond most people; it's pretty mangy and difficult to work with. It may not be complete, either; if validation passes it's trying to call a `setCheckboxDisplay` method that isn't defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Gottya, i suppose i was trying to finish something off, whilst our guy is stuck between bullets and tanks lol. No worries, will have to leave until he resurfaces, god willing. Many thanks

Comment: @422 Good luck--maybe working with someone on rentacoder or something; it shouldn't take *too* long, but it'd be hours, not minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
if($("input[name='internal[]']:checked").length > 0)) {
  alert("At least 1 checkbox checked!");
}
```